# Why does GNU Emacs use ksi(ξ) as its logo?

Tags: help

Why does GNU Emacs use ksi(ξ) as its logo, while most Lisp dialects use lambda(λ) as their logos?

[image]

not mean this one:

[image]

Comment: FYI, if it was ξ then written in English it would be xi, not ksi, which is ѯ. Wikipedia: [xi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_(letter)) [ksi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ksi_(Cyrillic)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't. It uses just an `E` that is suggestive of a gnu's horns.

Comment: I thought the new logo of emacs is a ksi(ξ). I think you mean the Emacs(公牛). My ksi is refer to the GNU Emacs' icon.

Comment: No. It is the letter `E`, rendered artistically to resemble a [gnu](https://www.google.com/search?q=gnu&oq=gnu&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l3j69i60l2.600j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @cmal: Specifically, it's a *cursive* E, not a print E, hence the curviness.

Comment: See the full story of the creation of the logo here: http://www.ee.ryerson.ca:8080/~elf/emacs/logo/

Comment: @Tyler That is the "公牛" logo. What I am curious about is the xi(ξ) or `E` icon. Thank you all the same.

Comment: @cmal The third page of the link describes the addition of the word Emacs to the logo. As Drew points out, there is no connection to the xi icon, it's just an E

Comment: @Tyler's link appears to be broken, 4 years later.  Here's a Wayback Machine link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160101141646/http://www.ee.ryerson.ca:8080/~elf/emacs/logo/

Answer (score 2):

See also https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsIcons

It is the letters "E" and "M" stylized to look like the horns of a Gnu.  Any resemblance to the Greek alphabet is coincidental.

Emacs version 22 put this symbol over an icon of a notepad.  Later versions put it in a circle, overlaid with a pen.